# When data is piped from one program via | is there a way to detect what that program was from the second program?

Tags: shell, command, pipe

Say you have a shell command like
    cat file1 | ./my_script

Is there any way from inside the 'my_script' command to detect the command run first as the pipe input (in the above example *cat file1*)?

I've been digging into it and so far I've not found any possibilities.
I've been unable to find any environment variables set in the process space of the second command recording the full command line, the command data the my_script commands sees (via /proc etc) is just _./my_script_ and doesn't include any information about it being run as part of a pipe.    Checking the process list from inside the second command even doesn't seem to provide any data since the first process seems to exit before the second starts.

The best information I've been able to find suggests in bash in some cases you can get the exit codes of processes in the pipe via PIPESTATUS, unfortunately nothing similar seems to be present for the name of commands/files in the pipe.    My research seems to be saying it's impossible to do in a generic manner (I can't control how people decide to run my_script so I can't force 3rd party pipe replacement tools to be used over build in shell pipes) but it just at the same time doesn't seem like it should be impossible since the shell has the full command line present as the command is run.

(update adding in later information following on from comments below)

I am on Linux.

I've investigated the /proc/$$/fd data and it almost does the job.    If the first command doesn't exit for several seconds while piping data to the second command can you read /proc/$$/fd/0 to see the value pipe:[PIPEID] that it symlinks to.   That can then be used to search through the rest of the /proc/*/fd/* data for other running processes to find another process with a pipe open using the same PIPEID which gives you the first process pid.

However in most real world tests I've done of piping you can't trust that the first command will stay running long enough for the second one to have time to locate it's pipe fd in /proc before it exits (which removes the proc data preventing it being read).   So if this method will return any information is something I can't rely on.

Comment: Are you on linux?  If so, try `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` and look at fd0.

Comment: Suppose `cat file1` was put in a script.  Would you want `my_script` to change its behavior according to the name of the script or the name of the command that the script was running?